# WordPress 4.7.2 update on multisite causes wp-admin redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite, redirect-loop, wp-admin

I have a website running multisite using a subdirectory setup. I have just tried updating my site to 4.7.2 and the update goes through and no errors happen during the installation, but then after the install is finished I am redirected to /wp-admin/network/about.php?updated which returns a 404 page. So then I try to go back to /wp-admin/ and I get a redirect loop error.

I have looked through at least 40 different articles, forums, and websites about WordPress multisite wp-admin redirect loop issues. I have tried everything I can possibly find to fix this issue, but nothing has worked. The main site works perfectly fine, but wp-admin is completely unaccessible.

Here are the things I have tried so far:

1. I tried clearing my cache and cookies multiple times, and the site is not using any caching plugins
2. I renamed my plugins folder to plugins.deactivate
   Just to be extra thorough I also updated active_plugins field in the wp_options table to a:0:{}
3. I tried removing multisite definitions from my wp-config.php file, but when that had no effect I put them back
4. I confirmed my .htaccess file matches the one listed here for 3.5+ multisite – https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite
5. I also tried switching it to the old version, just in case, but that did nothing so I switched it back.
6. I found a forum saying that they fixed the issue by commenting out a redirect at the bottom of /wp-admin/network/admin.php so I tried that but it did nothing so I uncommented it back to normal.
7. I found another forum saying you need to define cookie paths in wp-config.php. So I had tried that by adding the code below to my wp-config.php, but it didn’t work either so I removed it.

Cookie path code I tried:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Here is my wp-config.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'DBNAME');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'DBUNAME');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DBPASS');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'DBHOST');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

/**
 * Other customizations.
 */
define('FS_METHOD','direct');define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',0777);define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',0666);
define('WP_TEMP_DIR',dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/uploads');

/**
 * Turn off automatic updates since these are managed upstream.
 */
define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);


/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'XXXXXX';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Are you getting this error: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /FILEPATH/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1173`

Comment: I don't get any errors at all, just a too many redirects error page.

Comment: Probably not the same one I encountered when I updated then.

Comment: I just updated a multisite today and had no issues.
If you have any security plugins try disabling them until after the update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! After trying to install a completely fresh copy of WordPress to a new subdomain and immediately getting too many redirect errors I knew the issue had to be at the server level.

I checked my error logs in cPanel and found that it was throwing errors every time I tried to access anything in wp-admin because the files were writable by group with 0664 permissions.

I changed all files in wp-admin and wp-includes to 0644 permissions and bam! Everything works now!

If you are having this too many redirects issue as well check your error logs. I'm not sure if this is just my server or if WP added an extra level of security in the most recent update, but I'm just glad it's fixed now!